# $u$-Subtitution with a definite integral that has a constant gives different answer

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

I have the following integral:
$$\int_0^\pi (2+\cos^2(t)\sin(t))\,\mathrm dt$$

Choosing $u = \cos(t)$, I would get the following result:

$$2u - \frac{u^3}{3}$$

which is:

$$2\cos(t) - \frac{\cos^3(t)}{3}\Bigg|_0^\pi.$$ However, if I solve the same integral by taking the constant out as its own integral:

$$2\int_0^\pi\,\mathrm dt+\int_0^\pi\cos^2(t)\sin(t)\,\mathrm dt$$

And the computed antiderivative would be

$$2\pi-\frac{\cos^3(t)}{3}$$

Why this discrepancy? Which one is the right one?

Comment: You're forgetting the $\mathrm{dt}$ element which it multiplied by $2$$$\int 2\mathrm{d}t=\int-\frac2{\sqrt{1-u^2}}\mathrm{d}u\ne\int 2\mathrm{d}u$$

Comment: I am still confused by what you mean. Did I do the u-sub correctly for the first one? when I chose u = cos(t), and du = -sin(t)dt? Why is it different when I seperate the 2?

Comment: You didn't do the $u$-substitution correctly as I was explaining. You do not have $-\sin{(t)}\mathrm{d}t$ next to the constant $2$ so such a substitution doesn't work.

Comment: I understand now. When I divided by -sin(t) I forgot about the constant 2 and only divided the trig part. But could you elaborate a little more on how you got the second integral in your comment (the one with the radical in the denominator)?

Comment: Further explanation is given in the answer below.

Answer (score 2):

The latter is correct. You really only needed u-substitution for the trig part of that integral. You've incorrectly applied the substitution for $\mathrm dt$ when you used the substitution for the integral of the constant.

$$\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{\pi}2\,\mathrm dt = -\int_{u(0)}^{u(\pi)}\frac{2}{\sin(t)}\,\mathrm du &= -\int_{u(0)}^{u(\pi)}\frac{2}{\sqrt{1-\cos(t)^2}}\,\mathrm du\\ &= -\int_{1}^{-1}\frac{2}{\sqrt{1-u^2}}\,\mathrm du = \int_{-1}^{1}\frac{2}{\sqrt{1-u^2}}\,\mathrm du\\ 
&= 2\pi
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 2):

@JeqHar has given you the correct answer.

To see where your mistake was, remember that when you are doing a $u$-substitution, you are hoping to be able to realize the integrand in the form
$$\int f\bigl(g(t)\bigr)g’(t)\,dt$$
and then set $g(t)=u$, $g’(t)\,dt = du$, and thus get $\int f(u)\,du$.

Here, you are setting $u=\cos(t)$, so $(-1)\,du = \sin(t)\,dt$. However, your integral is
$$\int \Bigl( 2 + \cos^2(t)\sin(t)\Bigr)\,dt.$$
In order to do the substitution the way you want, you should be able to rewrite
$$2 + \cos^2(t)\sin(t)$$
in the form
$$K(t)\sin(t)\,dt$$
(a product) so that you can take the “$\sin(t)\,dt$” and turn it into a $du$, and then do the substitution into $K(t)$.  That would mean writing
$$\int \Bigl(2+\cos^2(t)\sin(t)\Bigr)\,dt = \int \left(\frac{2}{\sin(t)} + \cos^2(t)\right)\underbrace{\sin(t)\,dt}_{(-1)du}$$
Then you turned the $\cos^2(t)$ into $u^2$... but you turned $\frac{2}{\sin(t)}$ into $2$... which is incorrect. You can either turn it into a function of $u$ correctly, or you can separate it out, but you can’t just leave the $2$ alone.